# 'post' only for editor and administrator

Tags: user-access

How can I make it so that only Administrator and Editor could access 'post' post-type? (just like 'page' post-type)

I'm planning to only let Author and Contributor use the Custom-Post-Type which I've prepared beforehand...

Comment: You need to check a wordpress custom post type roles plugins.

Comment: @Foxsk8 We are a developer site, we try to figure out how it works, not where to download a replacement for our own thinking.

Comment: But Your idea is based on user roles. You need looking for roles functions, integration to get staff works like as you wish.

Comment: @Foxsk8 as you can see that can be solved with 8 lines of code. There is no *need* to look at plugins, you *can*, sure, but *need* is something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registered capabilities (and the other features) for registered post types are not saved in the database, but in a global variable, `$wp_post_types`.

Being a global variable, editing it is easy. However you'll also need to manually remove the menu item, otherwise authors and contributors will be able to see it even if they cannot create/edit posts.

In following function I'll set the capabilities for `post` post type coping ones from `page` post type.

```
add_action('init', 'restrict_posts', 1); // registration run on init with priority 0
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_post_from_menu', 1);

function restrict_posts() {
  global $wp_post_types;
  $wp_post_types['post']->cap = clone $wp_post_types['page']->cap;
}

function remove_post_from_menu() {
  if ( current_user_can('edit_others_pages') ) return;
  remove_menu_page('edit.php');
}
```